# Can I still use my Indefinite Leave to Remain Visa in my old passport to travel?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, passports, uk-residents

Friends and I are planning to travel to Europe this September, and I have an Indefinite Leave to Remain (ILR) in the UK in my old passport. Does ILR even have an expiration date? And getting a BRP now will cost me a fortune to get it done quickly. I have my new passport. Should I travel using both my old and new passports instead? I dont want to be held back by the Immigration when I return back to the UK

Comment: Have you never had a BRP?

Comment: [Replace your visa with a BRP](https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits/replace-visa-brp) combines expired passport with lost or stolen passport as a reason to get a BRP. That is not encouraging.

Comment: Check the vignette sticker in your old passport for an expiry date. Even with both your old and new passports you won’t be able to re-enter the UK if your visa has expired and you don’t have a BRP. You probably wouldn't even be allowed to board the plane.

Comment: Indefinite Leave to Remain lapses if you've been out of the UK for more than 2 years. If the ILR vignette (sticker) is in your old passport you present both old and new passports to the Immigration officer (IO) on arrival in the UK. If you've not been outside the UK for more than 2 years, the IO will stamp your new passport and should write above it 'VIPP' meaning 'visa in previous passport'. VIPP is used to indicate both ILR vignetts, or other UK visas.

Comment: I dont have a BRP, if I apply now. It will cost me £1000 to get it done really quickly and I dont have the budget for that one. And I checked my passport, it says valid until 24th of July 2019. Does that mean my ILR vignette expired?